# Use custom key values in a continuous legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Not sure if the title has been phrased optimally. However, here's what I'd like to do. I have the following demo graph:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, size=Petal.Length)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.6)
```

[image]

... and I would simply like to change which values are showing in the legend. Currently, all of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are showing. In this case, what if i wanted there to instead be 3 legend options with 1, 3, and 6? I have spent a fair bit of time looking into this and could not find a solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just add `scale_size(breaks = c(1, 3, 6))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this via `scale_size_continuous()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, size=Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.6) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(1,3,6))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>